# Not able to start Kibana, because port issue.

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have just downloaded elasticsearch 5.6, and kibana 5.6 to give a try.  What I have found is, whenever I have started the elasticsearch, it will fork a child process,

```
31615 30496  0 04:29 pts/1    00:00:04 ./../node/bin/node --no-warnings ./../src/cli
```

, and that child process will be using the port of "5601", which should be used for Kibana ?

Is there something I have missed here? For a beginner user, does anyone have a page where I can check the latest feature, running procedures of these 2 products ?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: I doubt that starting ES spins up a Kibana process... What command are you using?